# How to benchmark a single function call in Python?

Tags: python, benchmarking, microbenchmark

How to interactively (micro)benchmark a code expression in Python  (i.e. the equivalent of `@btime`/`@benchmark` in Julia) ?

I would like to benchmark interactively an expression (a function call), where the number of times this expression should be evaluated depends on its computational cost / variance....

I have tried `timeit.timeit` but I have some quesitons:

1. How do I interpret the time output of the following results:

```py
>>> a = 2.2
>>> timeit.repeat("round(a)", setup='from __main__ import a; gc.enable()', repeat=5,number=10)
[4.631001502275467e-06, 1.3809185475111008e-06, 1.2170057743787766e-06, 1.1718366295099258e-06, 1.1730007827281952e-06]
>>> timeit.timeit("round(a)", setup='from __main__ import a; gc.enable()', number=10)
5.741836503148079e-06
>>> timeit.timeit("round(a)", setup='from __main__ import a; gc.enable()')
0.11461802502162755
>>> timeit.Timer('round(a)', setup='from __main__ import a; gc.enable()').autorange()
(5000000, 0.4272152939811349)
```

It seems that when I go from `number` from `1` to `10`, the timing remains pretty stable, but then it grows of different order of magnitude....

2. Does it makes sense a workflow where I first create the `Timer` object once, and then I modify several times the code to evaluate and benchmark the modified Timer ? E.g.

```py
import timeit
import gc

bclass = timeit.Timer('round(1.1)','gc.enable()', globals=globals()) 


[...]


bclass.stmt = "small_3x2_nash.vertex_enumeration()"
bclass.autorange()

bclass.stmt = "small_3x2_nash.lemke_howson_enumeration()"
bclass.autorange()

bclass.stmt = "small_3x2_nash.support_enumeration()"
bclass.autorange()
```

(seems this is not possible, as I have tried very different code and the result of the timing remains almost the same)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the Timer class to enable de GC, as explained in the docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit

And instead of explicit import every variable/function that you want to use from **main**, you could pass `globals()` in the Timer arguments. In that way, all the globals variables, functions, etc will be passed to de evaluated function.

```
Python 3.10.10 (main, Mar  5 2023, 22:26:53) [GCC 12.2.1 20230201] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import timeit
>>> 
>>> a = 2.2
>>> 
>>> t = timeit.Timer('round(a)', globals=globals())
>>> 
>>> t.timeit(number=1000)
0.00042562399994494626
>>> t.autorange()
(5000000, 0.46861540100007915)
```

To enable GC you need also import the `gc`lib

```
import gc
t = timeit.Timer('round(a)', 'gc.enable()', globals=globals())
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't get the two things together (the globals and the gc.enable()). Also, how is the output interpeted? I notised that the time when you move `number` from 1 to 10 or so remains stable, but then increases

Comment: Edited, to use gc you also need to import the `gc` lib.